# A sentence from Oliver Twist and its meaning

Tags: meaning, popular-refrains, charles-dickens

Saw this in his book a few days, would someone help me find clarity in its meaning?

"*brass can do better than the gold what has stood the fire*"

**Here is the full context:**

> The man ran upstairs. Nancy remained, pale and almost breathless, listening with quivering lip to the very audible expressions of scorn, of which the chaste housemaids were very prolific; and of which they became still more so, when the man returned, and said the young woman was to walk upstairs.
>
> ‘It’s no good being proper in this world,’ said the first housemaid.
>
> ‘Brass can do better than the gold what has stood the fire,’ said the second.

Comment: it's best to include much more of the text around both sides of the quote.

Comment: Page 300 of which edition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Brass* refers to Nancy's rough 'brassy' insistence. *Gold* refers to the self-opinion of the 'chaste housemaids'. *Fire* refers to the process of refining gold, which removes impurities.

So they are saying that *It's unfair how being crude (like her) sometimes works better than being refined (like us).*